# Use external modules in Android

Tags: android, module

I am working on a Project, which uses small modules, which ive programmed as fragments so far. As it is far better to not having to change all the code, i wanted to know IF it is possible to use classes, that arent compiled in the project itself, but are saved elsewhere, so that i can add modules without having to recompile/change the original project.

Thanks for answers and cheers

Jacobus

Comment: [Check this](http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html) and [this](https://github.com/lukeFalsina/Grab-n-Run)

Comment: @Skynet thanks :D with the first glance this looks about right :)